# How to after refresh page resetting value in blazor?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, session-storage

I want get current use login when sore in `ISessionStorageService` normal work after user go to **Dashboard** page, **Dashboard** have a **layout** in layout page get `SessionStorage` value for current user login,

### Layout Page

```
h1>@UserInfo.FullName</h1>

@Body

@code {

    private LoginUser UserInfo = new LoginUser();

    async Task UpdateUserInfo() => UserInfo = await SessionStorage.GetItemAsync<LoginUser>("LoginUser");

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await UpdateUserInfo();
    }
}
```

**Login Page set value**

```
await SessionStorage.SetItemAsync("LoginUser", loginUser);
```

**Note: user login and switch between pages work  but when i want refresh page give a error**

> `InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendererd. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.`

Comment: You can't do js interop on that event, try [OnAfterRenderAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#after-component-render) like the error mentions.

Comment: You mean call in ‘OnAfterRenderAsync’ ? When i call in `OnAfterRenderAsync` userInfo is empty

Comment: This is the annoying thing about Blazor that I wasn't able to figure out yet. Why isn't there a standard and straightforward way to simply persist a certain set of per-user data across requests/refreshes/new tabs/whatever? This has been a major source of headache for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using pre-rendering, you cannot call JavaScript methods while this process is being taken place. Instead set the call to the UpdateUserInfo method
in the OnAfterRender(Async) pairs, like this:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
       if( firstRender )
       {
           await UpdateUserInfo();
           InvokeAsync( () => StateHasChanged());

        }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: use `OnAfterRenderAsync` but `UserInfo` field not updated

Comment: That's another issue, not related to the first one.

Comment: I think you need to rerender your page. Use: InvokeAsync( () => StateHasChanged());